# JS not calling function

Tags: constructor

Here is my calling html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Display Card Type</title>
</head>
<script src='Card.js'; ></script>      
<body>
<script>
    var card = new myCardType();
    var value = new myCardType();
    card.setCard('I am a club');
    value.setFace('I am an Ace');
    card.showSuit();
    value.showFace();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the separate function (saved in same folder).

```
function myCardType(){
    this.suit = suit;
    this.showSuit = function(){
        alert(this.suit);
}
    this.face = value;
    this.showFace = function() {
        alert(this.face);
}
    this.setCard = function (newSuit) {
        this.suit = newSuit;
}
    this.setFace = function (newValue) {
        this.face = newValue;
}
```

}

Spent ages reviewing this but just cannot see what is going on, grateful for any clues.

Comment: Please add what behavior you are seeing or errors you are getting, if any. This is part of writing an [MCVE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query). If you load the page with the console open, do you see any errors? Also your card.js is missing some punctuation. You should have semi-colons after those function declarations because you're assigning those functions to a variable on 'this', and there are some '}' missing at the end of the file.

Comment: This is still not doing anything - does anyone have an opinion on this please.

Comment: Could you maybe make a jsfiddle with your code and link to it?